# how can we save our applications hosted on a web server if one application calls system.exit(1)

Tags: tomcat, application-server

Suppose two applications are hosted on a web-server and from one application we calls system.exit(1), How will we save our second application from shutdown?

Comment: You won't (unless there is a security manager forbidding that). But why would you call System.exit() from a web application. That would be a huge bug, that just needs to be fixed, as any other bug. (Note: this is only true if your two webapps are being deployed to the same web container. Not if they are independant and each run in their own JVM)

Comment: @JBNizet It was an interview question. You are right we can edit security manager setting but don't we have any other way?